# How to obtain a permutation matrix swapping two rows of a matrix in Eigen3?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I would like to define a permutation matrix as follows:

```
PermutationMatrix<Dynamic, Dynamic> perm(n)
perm.setIdentity();
"swap(perm_row(i), perm_row(j))",
```

where `perm_row(i)` and `perm_row(j)` denote the `i`th and `j`th rows of `perm`, respectively. How to perform the statement `"swap(perm_row(i), perm_row(j))"` in Eigen3?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't need to perform other permutations, then you can do:

```
perm.indices()[i] = j;
perm.indices()[j] = i;
```

If you need to perform more swaps, then you can either swap columns and then transpose it:

```
for(...)
  swap(perm.indices()[i],perm.indices()[j]);
perm_row = perm.inverse();
```

or use [Eigen::Transpositions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transpositions.html).